# apply a function in data frame with if/else statement in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame looks like the following

```
data.1 <- data.frame(
  X1 = 6:10,
  X2 = 1:5,
  X3 = c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
)

  X1 X2    X3
1  6  1  TRUE
2  7  2 FALSE
3  8  3  TRUE
4  9  4 FALSE
5 10  5  TRUE
```

I want to create a new column X4 with the following logic:

```
if X3==NULL then X4=NULL
elseif X3==TRUE then X4=X1+X2 
else X4=X1-X2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried the following code which returns error. data.1$X4<-lapply(data.1,function(x) ifelse(data.1$X3==TRUE,data.1$X2-data.1$X1,data.1$X2+data.1$X1))

Comment: Please edit the question, don't add code to comments. Also, you say "returns error", tell us what that error is. Don't make us type in everything to get the error that you should provide up front. You suggest testing for `NULL` in a cell of a data.frame ... have you tried making a data.frame with a `NULL` in a cell?

Comment: BTW: since your `ifelse` is by definition doing vector math, and you are giving it vectors, why do you need the `lapply`? (Hint, you don't.)

Comment: thanks Alpha, I know I've got way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lapply` is for when your data is a list, which isn't what you're doing.

Firstly, you won't find a `NULL` entry in a `data.frame`. `NA`, sure, but not `NULL`, so you should be working around a `is.na()`. Next, you don't need to test `if(x==TRUE)`; R knows how to use `if(x)`. Okay, so down to business; you were most of the way there with your `ifelse`. You can assign a vector to the output of an `ifelse` and it will take care of the vectorisation for you

```
data.1$X4 <- ifelse(is.na(data.1$X3), 
                    NA, 
                    ifelse(data.1$X3==TRUE,
                           data.1$X1+data.1$X2,
                           data.1$X1-data.1$X2))

data.1
##   X1 X2    X3 X4
## 1  6  1  TRUE  7
## 2  7  2 FALSE  5
## 3  8  3  TRUE 11
## 4  9  4 FALSE  5
## 5 10  5  TRUE 15
```

That's ugly though. `dplyr` includes non-standard evaluation, which involves searching the namespace for columns, so you don't need to quote the data name every time you want to reference a column, making this much cleaner. `dplyr::mutate` changes a column.

```
library(dplyr)
mutate(data.1, X4 = ifelse(is.na(X3), 
                           NA, 
                           ifelse(X3, 
                                  X1+X2, 
                                  X1-X2)))

data.1
##   X1 X2    X3 X4
## 1  6  1  TRUE  7
## 2  7  2 FALSE  5
## 3  8  3  TRUE 11
## 4  9  4 FALSE  5
## 5 10  5  TRUE 15
```

Comment: thanks @Jonathan. Both answers worked well, the dplyr: mutate solution will make life easier.

Comment: Or use `with()` to get around the naming issue. Also, you don't need to explicitly test for `NA` as a comparison with `NA` will give an `NA` - so `with(data.1, ifelse(X3, X1 + X2, X1 - X2))` gives an appropriate result that is far from ugly.